# Connecting to remote MySQL via local machine

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I am trying to connect to a remote MySQL database via PHP that is installed on my local windows computer.

MySQL Version: 5.1.43

The remote database is set up to accept connections from my IP but I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: OK packet 6 bytes shorter than expected in "my file here"

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication in "my file here"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: How much "control" do you have over the remote MySQL server? Can you change configuration settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are in control of the remote server (i.e. you can change its configuration and maybe even update the schema of the mysql database) see [Cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575807/cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-old-authentication/1576473#1576473).
If you're not in control of the server see [Mysql password hashing method old vs new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892607/mysql-password-hashing-method-old-vs-new)