# getting error "Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords." while creating WCF service of hosted MySQL database

Tags: mysql, wcf, entity-framework

I have MySQL database hosted on server. I want to create WCF web service of that database. Actually I want to comsume WCF service in Windows Store App. I am following these articles.

[Using an Entity Framework Entity as a Windows Forms Data Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html)

[Making a Connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-visual-studio-making-a-connection.html)

But I am getting error `Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords.` Then searched Stack Overflow and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772479/authentication-with-old-password-no-longer-supported-use-4-1-style-passwords/15989284#15989284) solution, but it is also not working for me.

Please guide me to solve this issue.

PS : Please don't down vote this question, I have googled and searched in Stack Overflow but didn't get solution :(

**UPDATE 1**

I have applied command via phpMyAdmin in SQL query textbox. I also followed this [Mysql password hashing method old vs new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892607/mysql-password-hashing-method-old-vs-new), but getting same error that `"you have no SUPER privilege."`

Comment: How did you issue these commands? (mysql console or some GUI ?) Also, what is the version of the MySQL server you are connecting to?

Comment: I applied commands from phpMyAdmin. I first open database and then applied commnads from SQL query textbox. Server version in 5.5.28-29.3-log

Comment: It appears I had a wrong assumption in believing that issuing `SET SESSION old_passwords=0;` from PhpMyAdmin could cause an issue. I just tested and it really works fine. Please issue the following command: `SELECT user, host, password FROM mysql.user`. All values in the `password` column should begin with a `*` (star), is it the case?

Comment: I am getting error `SELECT command denied to user 'XXXXXX'@'localhost' for table 'user'` while issuing command `SELECT user, host, password FROM mysql.user`, please my update 1.

Comment: Then I am afraid you will have ask to be granted the SUPER privilege, or ask the administrator to run these commands for you. I assume you received a warning when you ran the first `SET PASSWORD` command, didn't you?

Comment: No, I didn't get problem. I have doubt that when I issue `SET SESSION old_passwords=0;` it has scope of only browser. So Visual Studio is throwing error still.

Answer (score 0):

I have not managed to solve the problem as the others who have responded, although I tried out everything that has been proposed. In the end it turned out that the server on which stood my DB is not updated phpMyAdmin since version 3.5.5, and is currently being used everywhere version 4.1.14 and it is a problem. The solution is to update your host phpMyAdmin or your own mySQL back to an earlier version in order to continue working on remote DB. You may need this knowledge in order to solve some doubts that have arisen. :)