# Access to mysql database from remote host via asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I'm having issues with connecting to a database on Windows Server (Windows Server Standard - yeah, it's an older server).  Here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm in the process of rewriting a classic ASP site in ASP.NET.  The conversion has to run in parallel and use the existing MySQL database on the old server.  I am developing the site on my pc and then uploading the site to a new server.

Here's the issue that I"m having:  I can run everything on my pc with no issues, but when I attempt to run the site on the new server, I'm unable to access the MySQL database.  I get MySQL Error 1045.

The firewall on the old server has been configured to allow connections from both my IP and the IP of my server.  I've created a user in MySQL that should allow access from any remote IP.

This is the exact exception that is being thrown:

```
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions XXXXXXXXXX:3306`
```

Any thoughts on how I can correct this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that the MySql .NET connector is the same version on the server as your local machine? What happens when you try and connect using mySQL command line tools on the server?

Comment: The MySQL connector is the same on my pc and the server.  I can use MySQL workbench with no issues on my PC and all command line tools seem to be working correctly on the "old" server.  I'm really baffled by this.

Comment: Hmmm.... Connection strings identical? Not a case of old password format: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892607/mysql-password-hashing-method-old-vs-new

Comment: The connection strings should be identical unless when I do the web deploy from VS2013 they're being changed.