# Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL for Yoomla on local machine

Tags: mysql, joomla, cpanel

Today I have got a new project that is in Joomla.
I have website code downloaded on my computer.
Website administration panel is cpanel.

I have never done anything with Joomla site before.

When I open website on my local machine (http://localhost/ppp/public_html/index.php) it says Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL.
However, I have changed configuration.php file (it was my guess that I need to change it):

```
//Before my changes it was the following:
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'reiuser_reiuser';
public $password = 'password';
public $db = 'reiuser_reiuser';

//After my changes:
public $host = '174.121.134.94'; //IP was displayed in cpanel
public $user = 'reiuser_reiuser';
public $password = 'password';
public $db = 'reiuser_reiuser';
```

I have read info about this error and most says to check connection data.
However, I can successfully connect with HeidiSql using those connection data (user/password/db were changed).

Maybe here is not enough information, but maybe Joomla developers can suggest what to do?
Which Joomla file is dooing connection? Maybe I can do some echos to understand the cause of error?
Website is using CPanel.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to use mysql_connect directly, I got something like 
mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Premature end of data (mysqlnd_wireprotocol...
The link for a sollution I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099434/premature-end-of-data-error-with-php).

"The above problem occures because of version in-compatibility between PHP and MySql. Mostly it may occurs during remote access of db."

I downgraded my php and apache (I am using wamp) and now connection is ok.

Answer (score 1):

you could try a mysql_connect(); just after your conf with a die() on the exception to be sure this is the used config and not an other config file

Comment: Sometimes when you have some strange problems, you forget the most simple things...