# "Connect failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" from php function

Tags: php, mysql, access-denied

I wrote some function used by a php webpage, in order to interact with a mysql database. When I test them on my server I get this error:

```
"Connect failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
```

I am able to use them on my pc (using XAMPP) and I can navigate through the tables of the database using the command line in the server. However, the webpage fails to connect. I've checked the password but with no results. It's correct (otherwise I could not log in to mysql from the command line).

The call of the function is the following:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "shop");
```

Do I have to set something in my server? Thanks

Edit:
PHP version 5.3.3-7+squeeze1
mysql version:  5.1.49-3
both on debian

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? What version of MySQL? It sounds similar to http://www.bitshop.com/Blogs/tabid/95/EntryId/67/PHP-mysqlnd-cannot-connect-to-MySQL-4-1-using-old-authentication.aspx

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I solved in this way:
I logged in with root username

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost
```

I created a new user with

```
CREATE USER 'francesco'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
```

then I created the database

```
CREATE DATABASE shop;
```

I granted privileges for new user for this database

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON shop.* TO 'francesco'@'localhost';
```

Then I logged out root and logged in new user

```
quit;
mysql -u francesco -p -h localhost
```

I rebuilt my database using a script

```
source shop.sql;
```

And that's it.. Now from php works without problems with the call

```
 $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "francesco", "some_pass", "shop");
```

Thanks to all for your time :)

Comment: Well, I tried everything and it was still showing issue, figured out, I had other user with same name for different host value in DB, with different passwords and privileges, removed these users and it worked,

Comment: where do you type in these commands? Im really new to this literally only started the other day. I'm using MAMP and trying to connect a database i set up in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @pete800 I cannot recall exactly but you have to use the terminal, not phpmyadmin. I do not know if the latter has support for the terminal, however. You have to access mysql directly from the terminal.

Comment: Dont understand where to type these command and exactly what and why? explain more please.

Comment: @Mr_Andrew you have to type this command through the terminal (the command line) of your OS. In Mac OS it may be Terminal, iTerm, in Windows Powershell, in Linux gnome-terminal, and so on. Once you get into the terminal you log in to the mysql client through the first command and then continue with subsequent commands.

Comment: I had a similar problem. As you know, `root` user has all privileges. No need to define a new user. My problem was due to case sensitivity. I have a DB called `sampledb` in MySQL and its name was written `sampleDB` in PHP code. I modified my PHP code and the problem was resolved.

Comment: This worked for me. I only had to add the extra user and grant privileges. The other things remained the same.

Answer (score 10):

Is there a user account entry in the DB for root@localhost? In MySQL you can set different user account permissions by host. There could be several different accounts with the same name combined with the host they are connecting from. The most common are root@127.0.0.1 and root@localhost. These can have different passwords and permissions. Make sure root@localhost exist and has the settings you expect.

I am willing to bet, based on your explanation, that this is the problem. Connecting from another PC uses a different account than root@localhost and the command line I think connects using root@127.0.0.1.

Comment: When I log in from the command line I use
`mysql -u root -p -h localhost`
and typing `select user()` I get _root@localhost_

Comment: and........ I did `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` so there should be no problems... yet mysql keeps on saying access denied... which obviously renders mysql quite useless.

Comment: ahhhh lied to by mysql again... there change password command was faulty I had to do `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'%' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');` mysql tricked me by making it look like there was only one password, when in fact mysql considers root@domain1 a totally different user than root@domain2....

Answer (score 8):

From what you've said so far, it sounds like a problem where the MySQL driver in PHP5.3 has trouble connecting to the older MySQL version 4.1. Have a look on http://www.bitshop.com/Blogs/tabid/95/EntryId/67/PHP-mysqlnd-cannot-connect-to-MySQL-4-1-using-old-authentication.aspx

There's a similar question here with some useful answers, [Cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575807/cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-old-authentication)

```
SELECT `User`, `Host`, Length(`Password`) FROM mysql.user
```

> This will return 16 for accounts with old passwords and 41 for accounts with new passwords (and 0 for accounts with no password at all, you might want to take care of those as well).
>   Either use the user managements tools of the MySQL front end (if there are any) or

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'User'@'Host'=PASSWORD('yourpassword');
FLUSH Privileges
```

Comment: It seemed the right solution but it doesn't work :| as I edited before php and mysql shall be compatible by version.. I will google further.. Also, I set as user password (different hosts) the same password but with no results..

Comment: @Francesco What's the output of `echo mysqli_connect_error();`?

Comment: the output is the one I used as title `Connect failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Moreover: with  `SELECT \`User\`, \`Host\`, \`Password\` FROM mysql.user` I got that all three root accounts have the same password hash..

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem too. But this was because of another reason.
My password began with character `$`... e.g. `$MyPassword`
I've changed it to `#MyPassword` and the problem is solved.

Comment: Solved our issue with an OpenCart install on Cpanel. We were looking for issues with mysqli on the server, turned out to be an invalid character in the password! Thanks.

Comment: @JaydenMeyer You're welcome; I'm so glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I never think of doing the same mistake again in future. it took so much time.

Answer (score 6):

Easy.

open xampp control panel -> Config -> my.ini edit with notepad. now add this below [mysqld]

```
skip-grant-tables
```

Save. Start apache and mysql.

I hope help you

Answer (score 5):

## Here maybe?

I believe that the code should be:

`$connect = new mysqli("host", "root", "", "dbname");`

because root does not have a password. the `(using password: YES)` is saying "you're using a password with this user"

Comment: don't repeat answers just add comments

Answer (score 1):

**TIP:**
comment out pid and socket file, if you can't connect to server..
mysql could be connecting with incorrect pid and/or socket file, 
so when you try to connect to server trough command-line it *"looks"* 
at the incorrect pid/socket file...

```
### comment out pid and socket file, if you can't connect to server..
#pid-file=/var/run/mysql/mysqld.pid
#socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is not identifying your user properly.  root@localhost.
Select the Mysql version your MAMP is using.

`/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump -uroot -p db_name > test_db_dump.sql`

I actually wrote an alias on my computer so I don't have to remember how to get to the bin directory.

`alias mysqldumpMAMP='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump'`

Which allows me to run this:

`mysqldumpMAMP -uroot -p db_name > test_db_dump.sql`

You can save an alias in your bash profile `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_rc`

Answer (score 1):

May be there password is not set and you are passing password as argument.
Try ommitting password argument during connection..

Comment: hi @shrinivas-manjithaya, thanks for your answer. It would definitely help to include an example of the code that you are suggesting to the user. Also if you have the ability to reproduce the error they are experiencing and provide directions on how to resolve this for the user it is more likely your answer will be helpful for them.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your privileges on **PHPmyAdmin** (WAMP), Note that your password and user name has not been created. So do create or edit it, that it might work with your sql connection in your php.
Hope it works

Answer (score -2):

Try initializing your variables and use them in your connection object:

```
$username ="root";
$password = "password";
$host = "localhost";
$table = "shop";
$conn = new mysqli("$host", "$username", "$password", "$table");
```

Comment: While that would make the code more readable, it doesn't solve the problem which has to do with incorrect authentication information and/or grants.

Comment: `$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $table);`  No double quotes needed.

Comment: don't repeat answers just add comments