# Undefined index and variable for user in php

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me, I got an error and I stuck many hours. I can't find what's wrong in the php script. I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Here's the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: error_message in C:\xampp\htdocs\vacation1.0.04\index.php on line 27
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: bdy_addin in C:\xampp\htdocs\vacation1.0.04\includes\header.inc.php on line 47
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: CurrentYear in C:\xampp\htdocs\vacation1.0.04\index.php on line 61
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: CurrentYear in C:\xampp\htdocs\vacation1.0.04\index.php on line 61

Here's the index.php script:

```
session_start();//start the session
define("DIR_PATH", "");//you must change the path for each sub folder

//SET PAGE VARIABLES
$year_to_view = (isset($_POST["year_to_view"]))?$_POST["year_to_view"]:"";
$user_name = (isset($_SESSION["ses_first_name"]))?$_SESSION["ses_first_name"]:"" . " " .   (isset($_SESSION["ses_last_name"]))?$_SESSION["ses_last_name"]:"" ;//concatenate first and last name
$year_option = "";

require(DIR_PATH."includes/db_info.inc.php");//database connection information
require(DIR_PATH."includes/cur_date.inc.php");//get the current fiscal year

$error_message = $_REQUEST["error_message"];

$hdr_addin = '
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function formload() {
    var username = document.LoginForm.username;
    if (username) username.focus();
}
//-->
</script>';


if($_SESSION["ses_login_success"] != 'Y'){
$bdy_addin = 'onLoad="formload();"';
}

if($_SESSION["ses_login_success"] == 'Y'){
$hdr_detail = 'Time Off Information For<br />'.$user_name;
}else{
$hdr_detail = 'Vacation Login'; 
}

 $cur_page_title = "Employee Summary";
 require(DIR_PATH."includes/header.inc.php");

 //IF THE USER SUCCESSFULLY LOGGED IN DISPLAY THEIR INFORMATION.
 if($_SESSION["ses_login_success"] == 'Y'){

//load options for select box of years in the database
$GetYr = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vf_year");
while($YrArray = @mysql_fetch_array($GetYr)){
    $CurYear = $YrArray["year"];
    
    if($CurrentYear == $CurYear){
        $selected = "selected";
    }else{
        $selected = "";
    }           
    $year_option .= "<option $selected>$CurYear</option>\n";
}

//Set variable to determine which year to view. If they did not choose a year, use the current fiscal year. 
if(!isset($year_to_view) || $year_to_view == "--Select a year to view--"){
    $year_to_view = $CurrentYear;       
}

//If the user has entered an email address display it.
if($_SESSION["ses_email"] != ""){
    $email_addr = $_SESSION["ses_email"];
}else{
    $email_addr = "Not available";
}

echo '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="700" id="tablepos">
  <tr>
    <td align="right"><b>Contact Email:</b> ' . $email_addr . '</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>         
  <tr>
    <td>
        <b>To request a vacation:</b><br />
        1. If you have an email address listed above, when vacation has been approved<br />
           you will receive an email to let you know.<br />     
        2. Click on the Calendar menu option at the top of the page to request vacation time.<br />
        3. Follow the instructions given on the Calendar page.
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr> 
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text14BkB" align="center"><u><span class="text14rdb">'.$year_to_view.'</span> <b>summary of time off for ' . $user_name . '</b></u></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp; </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
        <form method="POST" action="vacation_detail_all.php">
        <input type="hidden" value="' . $year_to_view . '" name="year_to_view">
        <input type="submit" value="View all time off as one grouping sorted by date" name="return">
        </form> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp; </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="700" id="datatable">
        <tr id="tableheader">
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Total<br />Hours</th>
          <th>Hours<br />Scheduled</th>
          <th>Hours Available<br />to Schedule</th>
          <th>Hours<br />Used</th>
          <th>Unused<br />Hours</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>';

                //get all of the time off types that the employee may view
                $SQL = @mysql_query("SELECT * from vf_to_type WHERE emp_viewable = 'Y' AND
                                    (dept_id = '0' OR dept_id = '$_SESSION[ses_dept_id]')");
                //initialize the cell background color
                $bgcolor = "#FFFFFF";
                while($Result = @mysql_fetch_array($SQL)){
                    $TypeID = $Result["to_id"];
                    $Descr = $Result["descr"];
                    $Valid_date = $Result["type_date"];
            
                    if($bgcolor == "#FFFFFF"){
                        $bgcolor = "#C0C0C0";
                    }else{
                        $bgcolor = "#FFFFFF";
                    }
            
                    //If there is a valid date for this vacation type let the user know
                    //valid date designates that the vacation type cannot be scheduled
                    //until that date or later.
            /*        if($Valid_date != "0000-00-00"){
                        $Type_Date = "Can't be used before: "  . date("m/d/Y",strtotime($Valid_date));
                    }
            */
                    //LOOKUP THE TOTAL VACATION TIME THE EMPLOYEE HAS EARNED FOR THIS TIME OFF TYPE
                    $GetVac = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vf_emp_to_hours WHERE to_id = '$TypeID' " .
                                        "AND year = '$year_to_view' AND emp_id = '$_SESSION[ses_emp_id]'");
                    $Vac_Array = @mysql_fetch_array($GetVac);
                        $Earned = $Vac_Array["hours"];
            
                     //IF THE EMPLOYEE HAS TIME EARNED GET DETAILS OTHERWISE SKIP THIS TYPE
                     if($Earned != ""){
                        //RESET ALL THE VARIABLES
                        $TtlUsed = 0;
                        $TtlScheduled = 0;
                        $TtlRemaining = 0;
                        $TtlToSchedule = 0;
                        $TtlUnused = 0;
            
                        //LOOKUP ALL OF THE EMPLOYEES SCHEDULED TIME OFF FOR THE CURENT TYPE
                        $Get_Scheduled = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vf_vacation WHERE " .
                                "to_id = '$TypeID' AND emp_id = '$_SESSION[ses_emp_id]' " .
                                 "AND year = '$year_to_view'");
                        while($Load_Sched = @mysql_fetch_array($Get_Scheduled)){
                            $Vac = $Load_Sched["hours"];
                            $VacDate = $Load_Sched["date"];
            
                            //FORMAT THE DATE FOR COMPARISON
                            $VacDate = strtotime($VacDate);
            
                            //TOTAL HOURS THAT ARE SCHEDULED
                            $TtlScheduled = $TtlScheduled + $Vac;
            
                            //IF DATE HAS PASSED. CONSIDER VACATION AS USED
                            if($VacDate <= $TodaysDate){
                                $TtlUsed = $TtlUsed + $Vac;
                            }
            
                            //IF DATE HAS NOT PASSED. CONSIDER VACATION AS REMAINING
                            if($VacDate > $TodaysDate){
                                $TtlRemaining = $TtlRemaining + $Vac;
                            }
                        }
                            //CHECK HOW MANY HOURS ARE LEFT TO SCHEDULE
                            $TtlToSchedule = $Earned - $TtlScheduled;
            
                            //CHECK HOW MANY HOURS ARE STILL UNUSED
                            $TtlUnused = $Earned - $TtlUsed;
            
                //AFTER RETRIEVING MORE INFORMATION. CONTINUE BUILDING TO THE INFORMATION
                echo '
            <tr>
              <td class="text12BkB" align="center" bgcolor="'.$bgcolor.'">' . $Descr . '<br /><span class="text09Wt">'.$Type_Date.'</span<br /></td>
              <td class="text12BkB" align="center" bgcolor="'.$bgcolor.'">' . $Earned . '</td>
              <td class="text12BkB" align="center" bgcolor="'.$bgcolor.'">' . $TtlScheduled . '</td>
              <td class="text12BkB" align="center" bgcolor="'.$bgcolor.'">' . $TtlToSchedule . '</td>
              <td class="text12BkB" align="center" bgcolor="'.$bgcolor.'">' . $TtlUsed . '</td>
              <td class="text12BkB" align="center" bgcolor="'.$bgcolor.'">' . $TtlUnused . '</td>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="'.$bgcolor.'">
               <form method="POST" action="vacation_detail.php" style="margin-bottom:0;">
                <input type="hidden" value="' . $year_to_view . '" name="hdnYear">  
                <input type="hidden" value="' . $TypeID . '" name="TOType">
                <!-- <input border="0" src="images/detail.gif" name="I1" type="image" width="46" height="11"> -->
                <input border="0" name="I1" type="submit" value="Details" style="background:black;border:none;color:white;">
               </form>
              </td>
            </tr>';
    }            
}
 echo '</table>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr> 
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>By default the current fiscal year is loaded. To view other years change the selection below.</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr align="center">
    <td><form method="POST" action="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'">
        <select size="1" name="year_to_view">
            <option>--Select a year to view--</option>
            '.$year_option.'    
        </select>&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Reload Page" name="B1">
        </form>
    </td>
  </tr>      
</table>     
 
  ';
 //If the user isn't logged in display a login screen
}else{
echo '
<p align="center"><b>Please login to work with pages on this site!</b></p>
<form name="LoginForm" action="login.php" method="post">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="250" id="datatable" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      &nbsp;
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#C0C0C0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="150">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"align="right">&nbsp;Username&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="150"> <input type="text" name="username" size="16" maxlength="16" >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100"align="right">&nbsp;Password&nbsp; </td>
          <td width="150"> <input type="password" name="password" size="16" maxlength="16" >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="150">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="150"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" >
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="150">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
&nbsp;
</form>';
}
?>
```

Here's the head.php scipt:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title><?PHP echo $cur_page_title; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?PHP echo DIR_PATH."css/site.css" ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="<?PHP echo DIR_PATH."css/print.css" ?>">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?PHP echo DIR_PATH."includes/site.js"; ?>"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 m_21010 = 0;
 m_21020 = 0;
 <?PHP 
 if($_SESSION["ses_super_admin"] == 1 || $_SESSION["ses_is_admin"] == 1){
echo "m_21030 = 2;\n";
}else{
echo "m_21030 = 1;\n";  
 }
  ?>

 //-->
 </script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
function hideitem(selectcnt) {
if(! selectcnt)
    return;

if(document.all){
    for(i=0; i<selectcnt; i++){
        ObName = "HideItem"+i;
        document.getElementById(ObName).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
}
function showitem(selectcnt) {
if(! selectcnt)
    return; 
if(document.all){
    for(i=0; i<selectcnt; i++){
        ObName = "HideItem"+i;
        document.getElementById(ObName).style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
 }
</script>
<?PHP echo $hdr_addin; ?>
</head>
<body style="margin-top:0; margin-left:0;" <?PHP echo $bdy_addin; ?>
<div id="header">
<img src="<?PHP echo DIR_PATH."images/company_logo.gif"; ?>" alt="my company" width="165" height="70" border="0">
<div id="pagetitle"><?PHP echo $hdr_detail; ?></div>
<?PHP require(DIR_PATH."includes/menu.inc.php");//Menu pages ?>    
</div>
<?PHP
if(isset($error_message))
{ 
    echo '<span class="textError">'.$error_message.'</span>';
}elseif(isset($good_message))
{
    echo '<span class="textGood">* '.$good_message.'</span>';   
}
 require_once(DIR_PATH."includes/config.inc.php");  
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: Remove one of the `;` at the end of `(mysql_error());;`

Comment: Seems like your MySQL credentials are not correct. Check that username exist and can access that particular database

Comment: I try to change the username into root and i leave blank in the password but i still get an error

Answer (score 0):

Please check all database field name and your form field name....

All are insert same.

```
$db_info['password'] = "user";
```

Should be a black

```
$db_info['password'] = "";
```

Comment: I still have an error
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'vacation'Can not connect

Comment: Check database name...

Comment: when i changed the username and password into root. I got this error: Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\vacation1.0.04\includes\db_info.inc.php on line 9
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Give me a all project file and i will check.
rajeshprajapati5291@gmail.com
email all file .zip

Comment: I sent it to your email already, my email is tenkepadu@gmail.com

Comment: Ok Check Your email
all are done

Comment: Hello friend whats going on
Code are working or not
please give me a one reply

Comment: Hi its working, but there's a new display errors, please check your email

Comment: any line found error then add a '@' in below '$'.....
and chk

Comment: eg:- Like @$_SESSION["ses_login_success"]

Comment: Hi! How about the sub menus of administration tab?

Comment: line number?
please error msg copy past

Comment: there's no error dipsplay but when i click the administration tab, nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

```
Notice: Undefined index: year_to_view in C:\xampp\htdocs\vacation1.0.04\index.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: ses_first_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\vacation1.0.04\index.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined index: ses_last_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\vacation1.0.04\index.php on line 21
```

These notices are from your index.php file Try to print the $_POST variable whether its posted or not

Just print the POST varible on form . Better you need to check before assign

//SET PAGE VARIABLES

```
$year_to_view = (isset($_POST["year_to_view"]))?$_POST["year_to_view"]:"";
$user_name = (isset($_SESSION["ses_first_name"]))?$_SESSION["ses_first_name"]:"" . " " . (isset($_SESSION["ses_last_name"]))?$_SESSION["ses_last_name"]:"" ;//concatenate first and last name
$year_option = "";
```

for the DB access denied error you should pass your password as empty

Comment: Still have an error Notice: Undefined index: ses_last_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\vacation1.0.04\index.php on line 21
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'vacation'Can not connect

Comment: did you change the line on 21

Comment: update your question with code you have. for DB error refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445917/connect-failed-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes)

Comment: i update already the code in my question