# Can access mysql database using terminal, but I get "access denied" message when using php

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ubuntu

When logging into mysql in my terminal, everything works expected. But when I run my webpage with

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password");
if($conn->connect_error) {
   die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "connected successfully";
```

I get "connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".
I have tried resetting the root password. I have tried granting all permissions to root. I am absolutely positive that I am entering my username and password correctly in the php file.

I'm running a LAMP server on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I have php 5.5.9, mysql 5.5.40, and apache 2.4.7.

Can anyone help?

Comment: what happens if you try 127.0.0.1 or the machine's local IP address ex, 192.168.1.25 instead of localhost?

Comment: add database name which you are trying to connect in 4th parameter `$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password","DB_NAME");`

Answer (score 2):

PHP requires you to fill in the username, password and database name for the database you are trying to connect to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "database");
```

Comment: I've tried this; it still doesn't work. I get the same results.

Comment: Are you sure the database is hosted on the same server as the webserver? Try filling in the IP you use when logging in through the terminal in the PHP file, instead of localhost.. Make sure you also use the code above with the database name

Comment: I'm doing all of this locally. I have everything installed and running from the same machine. I just got a mechanical keyboard and I'm just doing some web stuff for fun.

Comment: Ah okay, did you restart MySQL after resetting/changing your password?

Comment: Yes. I ran

    sudo service mysql restart

Comment: Try adding a new user and giving it permission to a new database: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445917/connect-failed-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes

Answer (score 0):

Try `mysqli_connect_errno()`

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password");
if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
   die("connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "connected successfully";
```

Checkout Manual:

[connect_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php)

`Warning
The mysqli->connect_error property only works properly as of PHP versions 5.2.9 and 5.3.0. Use the mysqli_connect_error() function if compatibility with earlier PHP versions is required.`

Comment: This produces the same results as my original code.