# How to resolve "Access denied for user X" errors in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Error:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'Rohit'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\myprograms\db.php on line 8
>   Connection failed: Access denied for user 'Rohit'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Code:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT cid, fname, lname FROM face";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - Name: ". $row["firstname"]. " " .      $row["lastname"] . "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: So, your connection failed because the user is denied access?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Connect failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" from php function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445917/connect-failed-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes)

Comment: Once you fix the connection your echo will still fail because the columns you are requesting are fname and lname, not `$row["firstname"] $row["lastname"]` so either alias them or change those indexes.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you try to use incorrect username, password or host. 
Try to create new user from phpmyadmin page:

Open "Users" tab > select *Global privileges* checkboxes > type new *User name*, *Host* and *Password* and click to "Go" button.

After this try to set this new *username*, *password* and *host* in  **new mysqli()** constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are receiving means that the database connection failed. If you are using localhost on a Windows apache server it's common that the login to the database server is:

> server=localhost
> user=root
> password= (blank)
> databasename= your database name