# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'10.2.1.19'

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello i still getting this error...can anyone explain me why is there `10.2.1.19`? because in my config db file there is `localhost` instead of `10.2.1.19`..i tried to type `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` but nothing...still `10.2.1.19`

My configdb file:

```
 <?php
 $mysqli=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','user','','table') or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
?>
```

Thanx for help

Comment: Are you sure that error is coming from that line of code? Both the host and the username are different. I'm pretty sure it's not!

Comment: Do you think that this isn´t from configdb file? i check other files and let you know...

Comment: check your hosts file (c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts).. maybe localhost is declared as `10.2.1.19` there, or the .htaccess file in your project

Comment: @ZoltanToth i checked it and nothing...my localhost name is declared as `127.0.0.1` or `::1`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe because of User name and password. Pass valid username, password and DB Name

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Hello, now i getting error `Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'revenge'@'10.2.1.19' (using password: NO)` ...i checked my username and password in phpmyadmin and its correct...still _10.2.1.19_

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445917/connect-failed-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes

This link may be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanx for reply i try it and let you know

Comment: i tried and nothing...still getting same error :/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is:

```
<?php
 $mysqli=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','user','','table') or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
?>
```

You must to connect do database before try table

```
<?php
 $mysqli=mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','user','','DATABASE_NAME_HERE') or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
?>
```

If this still doesn't work, try to set some password, '123' for example, and try connection again. I recommend you to use mysqli class:

```
$some_variable_name = new mysqli('server_name','user_name','password','database_name');
$some_sql_command = "your SQL without ; at final";
$some_variable_name->query($some_sql_command);
$some_variable_name->close();
```

Go to php.net manual and see all commands.

I'm not an expert in configs, .ini files and these things, so I can't tell nothing about the modified IP.