# php/mysql connection error(with config file)

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a login/register system for a website but when i'm trying to connect to the database it gives this error:

> **Warning**: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 17

I'm using a external config file wich is been imported.

My config file:

```
// Connection details
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";
```

My connection code:

```
// Create connection
   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
```

I found one solution that worked to connect but then my config file was useless.

No config but only this:

```
// Create connection
   $conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password', 'database');
// Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
```

If someone nows a solution where i can keep using my config file please post it here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Access denied: your username and/or password are wrong, or your mySQL server not allow that user from localhost (strange...), or your have to configure your mySQL server

Comment: if your 2nd solution works, you can change in this sense config file! $password='password', $dbname='database'. Side note: password='password' don't seem the very best, also connecting as 'root'...

Comment: @fusion3k my account/password are OK, i don't know if my mysql server does, i did'nt configured my mysql server.

Comment: @fusionk3 i'm not going to show you my password on this site!

Comment: Do you have phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @fusionk3 yes i do why?

Comment: well done! (referring to password) So, change the working password in config file. Otherwise, you can add/change users and permissions in phpMyAdmin: [see more](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/user_management)

Comment: @fusionk3 how do you mean

Comment: @fusionk3 can you invite me for chat?

Comment: you say: "I found one solution that worked", then you can add these values to your config file. Ok?

Comment: Are you actually including the config file properly? Can you post more of the code to show the inclusion of the file, and then the attempt to connect using the variables inside that config?

Comment: Your server seems to have differences credentials for root@localhost and for root@127.0.0.1, or you're not including properly your credentials file properly. Try to print the credentials just before connecting, and confirm that they're what you configured. If that's the case, then you might have to check your server to see if you have different users.

Comment: @fusion3k i have them in my config The config is included with require(/classes/config.class.php); i Will Try

Comment: @SourceMatters iT is included with require

Comment: @NunoPereira how do you mean i Will Try to print

Comment: echo "sn=$servername, u=$username, p=$password, db=$dbname;"); // then connect and so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if the connection works with this values:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'password', 'database');
```

But not with this values:

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "cloud";
```

Why don't you just set the "working" values into your config file. So it would look like this:

```
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";
```

Another solution which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445917/connect-failed-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes) includes the creation of a new user, so you don't connect via root, but the new created user.

Comment: Sorry but i forgot to change The config to just basic The crendentuals in The config are The real ones And The other fake

Comment: I changed my question van you look again