# Can't connect to local MySQL server in R

Tags: mysql, r, database, server

I am learning how to use MySQL in R with the package RMySQL:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_database.htm

but when I try to connect to the DB provided in the example

```
mysqlconnection = dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'root', password = '', dbname = 'sakila', host = 'localhost')
```

I get:

```
 Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

My guess is that I am running it simply on my laptop (mac os), so if my guess is right (?) I need some virtual server.

Do you know any R package that does so? Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: I got a similar problem and fixed it by using RMariaDB instead of RMySQL. Now it works perfectly (RMySQL is deprecated).

Answer (score 3):

First check your sql service is running.

service mysqld start

Then try mysql -u root

If not solve issue from above solution try with host = '127.0.0.1' instead of localhost. Because 127.0.0.1 use TCP/IP connector. Unless localhost run with socket connector.

Comment: thanks, should the "service" and "mysql" commands be run in the R promp?

Comment: Nop. your os console.

Comment: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/start-stop-mysql-from-the-command-line-terminal-osx-linux/

Comment: I installed mysql, started it and typed: sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
Password:
com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld: Already loaded,
then in the R prompt:
mysqlconnection = dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'root', password = '', dbname = 'sakila', host = '127.0.0.1')
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Pls check here for solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445917/connect-failed-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes

Comment: `host = '127.0.0.1' instead of localhost` helped me

Comment: Host means mys sql connection host. [mysqlconnection = dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'root', password = '', dbname = 'your_db_name',host = 'localhost']

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, but the instructions in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_database.htm worked well for me. This are my steps

**1. Install and load "odbc" and "RMySQL" packages**

```
library(odbc);library(RMySQL)
```

**2. Setup the connection**

```
mysqlconnection = dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'root', password = '', dbname = 'your_db_name',host = 'localhost')
```

**3. List all your tables in your_db_name**

```
dbListTables(mysqlconnection)
```

**4. Now you can write queries**

```
result = dbSendQuery(mysqlconnection,"select * from your_table_name limit 0,30")
```