# Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I get this message if i run my register.

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'user'); 
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'test');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection)); 
}
?>
```

Comment: is your password `user` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Connect failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" from php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445917/connect-failed-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes)

Comment: You have to check your database credentials first.

Comment: im using phpMyadmin, can u tell me how to check?

Comment: and @teeyo no thats not my password its my database name.

Comment: @VincentJoeyFermalan the database name is the last parameter, the third is the password, if you don't have it, you pass an empty string!

Comment: @VincentJoeyFermalan So your database name is "user" and then afterwards you try and select a database...? What

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you don't have a password :

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test'); 

// OR with a P@$$w0rd

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'P@$$w0rd', 'test');
```

[`mysqli_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) takes four parameters:

1. Database host (if this is a local machine that will be "127.0.0.1" or "localhost"
2. Database username (local machine will be "root")
3. Database password (local machine will be "")
4. Database name (this is to save having to call mysqli_select_db)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i already edit the configs in mysql and set the password to ' ' (no password).