# How to Access a local MySql database from a remote server hosted in godaddy

Tags: php, mysql, server, backend

I am trying to access a database which is in root@localhost from a website hosted by godaddy.

i created a php file in the project folder and trying to access the local mysql database

here is the code

//actionpage.php

```
<?php

$db=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","cancan","canpass","test");


if (!$db) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

it gives me the error on the browser

Connection failed: Access denied for user 'cancan'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

The website i created is just static html without a back end..

I am pretty new to back end developing , Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Connect failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" from php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445917/connect-failed-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes)

Comment: When you say "local" do you mean "On the same server as the HTTP service" or "On your development machine"?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is a **local** loopback; essentially it's an alias for *this server* so, no, by definition that won't connect to a remote server - you'd need its WAN IP plus the access and permissions set up correctly.

Comment: "Connect failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" from php function – Anurag Srivastava  this doesnt solve my problem i have granted all permissions through myphpadmin

Comment: @Quentin on my local machine, is it possible to access a local database from a remote server

Comment: @CD001 i have granted all permissions for user databae and table ,, i dont have a backend for my website i am trying to create one using a simple login form

Comment: @NeenaSusan - but it *sounds* like you're trying to access a database on a **different machine** (e.g. your local one, not the one on GoDaddy) ... which isn't a great idea tbh, but it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as Godaddy doesn't block outgoing MySQL connections and your ISP doesn't block incoming MySQL connections, this is **technically** possible.

You would need to:

1. Configure MySQL to listen on your computer's external network interface (i.e. not on a UNIX socket nor on the loopback IP address).
2. Ensure that the MySQL service is available on the Internet (which will probably mean configuring your Internet router to perform port forwarding for the MySQL port from the Internet to your development machine)
3. Change the connection string in your PHP so it connects to the hostname or IP address of your computer on the Internet (probably your router's external IP address).

You'd probably want to ensure you have a static IP address on the Internet so that you don't need to update the PHP every time your IP changes.

---

This, however, will be slow (because your MySQL traffic has to go back and forth across the Internet) and risky from a security perspective.

So **don't do it**. Get a MySQL service from Godaddy.

Comment: if i get a mysql service from godaddy , i am i going to create a database in there panel ? can i use the same query to connect it with my server or how does it work ?

Comment: Is it ok to save my php files in the project folder?? i saved the php file with html files and accessing the php file from one of  the html forms

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy can't access database which is hosted on your computer. For that to be possible  your computer must have a [Public IP address](http://www.whatismypublicip.com), It's only that way you can connect website hosted on GoDaddy to your local database and for that you must reference you local computer by their Public IP address and not as *localhost* within your phone script.

When you use **localhost** in script host on GoDaddy It will not reference your computer but the server on which that script is hosted

Comment: i need to host a database in godaddy and can use the same script to connect to that database?

Comment: Didn't they give you database access when you register for your hosting plan

Comment: i was planning a static html page without a backend then. but now going to implement the back end because i have to use some forms

Comment: Do you have access to some kind of cpanel account

Comment: yes can i create a database from there for the existing website?