# Java MariaDB connection error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

I can't start my program, because whenever I try to open the datebase connection
with my MariaDB I get this error.

`java.sql.SQLException: Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.QueryException: Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I tried to reboot my computer, restart MariaDB, even reinstalling MariaDB, but none of them worked.
Interestingly I can somehow connect to the database with HeidiSQL.
It's funny, because last time I had the same problem and I couldn't connect with HeidiSQL either. The solution was simple, I had to restart MariaDB, but now it doesn't work.

I'm using Windows 10, Java 14, MariaDB 10.4.
This seems important as I've checked on all related issues and I still couldn't solve the problem.

Has anyone faced with this this issue before?

Comment: Can you connect using the command line `$ mysql -u root -p` ?

Comment: I can connect to it.

Comment: Strange! could you try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445917/connect-failed-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes

Comment: Hm... Even stranger! I tried that yesterday, but it didn't work then, but now it looks like it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Lol :D some time happens