# User can access MySQL DB through workbench, but not through VB .NET Code. Using ssl tunel to external server

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-connector

I am using same connection data, TCP/IP over SSH: ssh hostname, username, password, MySQL Hostname, server port, username, password

I have used MySql.Data.MySqlClient and MySqlConnector, and what I get is: "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'myuser' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'" or "MySqlConnector.MySqlException: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'"

I am using the same user and password I use in workbench, where it runs ok

I have tried this code

```
connectionInfo = New PasswordConnectionInfo("w.x.y.z", 22, "MyUserSsl", "MyPasswordSsl") With {
        .Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
        }
        client = New SshClient(connectionInfo)
        client.Connect()
        If Not client.IsConnected Then
            MsgBox("Wrong")
        End If

        portFwld = New ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 0, "127.0.0.1", 3306)
        client.AddForwardedPort(portFwld)
        portFwld.Start()

        con = New MySqlConnection With {
        .ConnectionString = "port=" + CStr(portFwld.BoundPort) + ";Database=MyDB;Data Source=localhost;User Id=MyUserDB;Password=MyPassword"
             }
```

and  this `portFwld = New ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 3305, "127.0.0.1", 3306)`

and this `portFwld = New ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 3306, "127.0.0.1", 3306)`

and also this

```
con = New MySqlConnection With {
        .ConnectionString = "Database=MyDB;Data Source=localhost;User Id=MyUserDB;Password=MyPassword"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there is user permissions issue
see gc5 answer:

["Connect failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" from php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445917/connect-failed-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes)

Comment: Thanks. Lot of cases there, but none helped me to fix my problem

Comment: did you check the firewall ?

Comment: No, because I can connect through workbench with same settings