# Cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Yes, this is a common issue - I found a Stack Overflow ticket that is perfect for this:

[Cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575807/cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-old-authentication)

Except... I don't have the privileges to run those MySQL commands on my shared hosting provider (Site5). When I asked them, they told me to screw off since I was accessing it from my local computer (which I do only to test web applications before committing/deploying my code). I am using the newest build of XAMPP on Windows 7 and it has PHP 5.3.5.

At any rate, I do not have root access and cannot change the password. They will not run these commands for me. What can I do?

EDIT: Also, when I enable PHP 5.3.5 on my shared host, the database connections work fine despite the old MySQL version and old_passwords file. I did this by adding a handler in .htaccess and confirmed it through phpinfo(). Is this a remote connection issue?

Comment: So you're trying to connect remotely to MySQL on your host? If so, many will not allow this for security purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did: I conceded by replicating the database on my local machine and changing the connection string to "localhost" rather than pointing at the shared server specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Your host may not allow remote database connections - a perfectly reasonable security measure, especially if it's shared hosting.

If you need to be able to do such things, you'll more than likley need to get a VPS or dedicated server. However there may be a very few that allow it for shared hosting.

Comment: My shared host did allow this (and still does) if I use PHP 5.2, however. Any ideas?