# Codeigniter Remote Database Connection Issue

Tags: php, mysql, linux, codeigniter, database-connection

A Codeigniter project(***in windows***) is required to connect with a Remote Mysql Database(***in linux server***). here is my database.php configuration.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and it gives an error

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: *:\****\***\htdocs\project\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 124
```

but i can access the remote mysql database via **Phpmyadmin** and **Heidisql** using the same username and password. (all privilages granted)

Here is Remote Database configuration

```
Server version: 5.0.95
Protocol version: 10
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
MySQL client version: 5.0.95
Used PHP extensions: mysql
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Take a look at this, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107449/connecting-to-a-remote-database-through-codeigniter). It may be due to the port configuration.

Comment: If you are using codeigniter 3, the mysql driver has been removed. Try with pdo or mysqli instead. See : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html#explanation-of-values

Comment: @AdrienXL Deprecated, not removed - that's deffinately not the problem here. But otherwise, yeah - go with mysqli.

Comment: Also, judging by the line number shown in that error message - the OP is using 2.x.

Comment: changed the `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';` to `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';` but no improvements. when tried with `pdo` it returns `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid data source name'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue before a couple of months ago when connecting to the remote mysql server in linux.

I tried this in mysql via PHPMYADMIN

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'old_passwords'` and  it says me `ON`

it means that `old_passwords=1` in `my.cnf` file in the server mysql configuration.

Solution for this problem is by updating the `password` for the corresponding user

Reference : [Error: mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831183/error-mysqlnd-cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-the-old-insecure-authenticatio)

Comment: Just tried this, no effect in codeigniter. it still return the same error that i mentioned on the question. but when i tried with a normal php programs it returns `Warning: mysql_connect(): mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication...`

Comment: Update the database password again with nothing. and then try to connect with no password.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help, but I did encounter similar issue before.

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

instead of

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

Comment: @ShifanaMubi, that is unfortunate. I checked your settings based on my working projects just to make sure and they should work. So, you probably are left to consider 1.) firewall? 2.) correct credentials (host, user, pwd).

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

Create a **user with all privilages**, Remember to **set host to %**

Edit mysqld.cnf and set "bind-address = 0.0.0.0" (may be /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf)

Restart mysql