# Could not connect to MySql

Tags: php, mysql, iis

I am getting problem in connect to mysql server. I installed PHP fast cgi with iis 7 via Web installer platform of windows. Everything is ok until i'm trying to connect mysql server, it's alway fail. Here is my code :

```
class MySqlDatabase{
    private $mysql;
    private $host;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $db_name;

    function __construct($host, $username, $password, $db_name){
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->db_name = $db_name;
    }
    public function connect(){
        $this->mysql = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, 
                       $this->password) or 
                       die("Could not connect to database. ". $this->username . 
                       "@" . $this->host . " passwrod: YES!");
        if (!mysql_select_db($this->db_name))   die("Cannot select database!");
    }
}
$database = new MySqlDataBase($host,$username,$password,$db_name);
$database->connect();
```

Comment: check your mysql username and password is correct

Comment: i checked username and password by connect to mysql server via SQLyog software, everything is ok, i connected. I think i got problem about config iis maybe

Comment: If you don't see any errors or warnings, enable them temporarily in your `php.ini` file using the `DisplayErrors` directive.

Comment: fwiw, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.  if you want an OO interface to your database, try out [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: _this is what you will get... this is what you will get... when you use `mysql_*`_ (Radiohead). `mysql_*` extension is being deprecated and shouldn't be used to write new code anymore. Look into `PDO` for a safer, better OO DB extension, or (if needs must) `mysqli_*`. Note the `i`, it stands for _improved_

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your MySql service is running.
2. Make sure your credentials are correct, try with MySql Workbench to see if you have a connection.
3. Make sure your script has the correct credentials as well.
4. Make sure your script targets the machine where the service is running, e.g. `localhost` port `3306`, just like MySql Workbench.

Comment: i don't run mysql service in localhost, i run it in a remote server and orther software like SQLyog still connected

Comment: If you try to connect to a remote database server: Have you opened required ports on your server?

Answer (score 0):

You obviously wrong credentials to connect to the database.
That's why you get the error " Could not connect to MySQL".
Check your variables and your username and password you send for the connection to be achieved.

Comment: i checked it, credentials are correct and i send correct credentials to mysql_connect function

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this, without class declaration:

```
// we connect to localhost at port 3307
$link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:3307', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: i've got message error: Could not connect: mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file

Comment: Try to reset mysql user password or restart mysql server on CentOS:
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart

on Debian:
/etc/init.d/mysql restart

Comment: thanks all, i've solved my problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831183/mysqlnd-cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-the-old-insecure-authentication?answertab=votes#tab-top