# XAMPP localhost issue with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, localhost

I am getting this warning in my localhost using XAMPP

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file in C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\dbconnect.php on line 135
```

How do I fix this warning and what does it mean?

Comment: Just follow the directives in the error message.

Comment: post the `mysql_connect` code from `dbconnect.php` here to judge the problem may be you have written a wrong password

Comment: Read this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831183/mysqlnd-cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-the-old-insecure-authentication

Answer (score 0):

go to your xampp folder directory : xampp/htdocs/ xampp/mysql.php

you will find this code on the page:

`<?php
    if (@mysql_connect("localhost", "pma", "")) {
        echo "OK";
    } else {
        echo "NOK";
    }
?>`

so all you have to do is exchange the whole code with this below:

`<?php
    if (@mysql_connect("localhost", "pma", "")) {
        echo "OK";
    } else {
        $err = mysql_errno();
        if ((1044 == $err) || (1045 == $err) || (1130 == $err)) {
            echo "OK";
        } else {
            echo "NOK";
        }
    }
?>`

and there you have your error fixed in a jiffy!!

Answer (score 0):

Log onto your XAMPP's PHPMyAdmin and run the following query inside of PHPMyAdmin

```
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_old_mysql_password')
```

where your_old_mysql_password should be replaced with your current MySQL password.

This should fix your problem.

You can also simply reinstall XAMPP (to another directory if possible), which should guarantee a fix since it's self-contained.