# Connecting to MySQL 4.1 from PHP5.3.13 command line interface

Tags: mysql, php, my.cnf, mysqlnd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575807/cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-old-authentication)

I am posting this question because I could not find any working solution. So please excuse.

I am using mysql 5.5.24 and PHP 5.3.13 (both from  WAMP2 installation)

While I am able to connect to the database from php script through the webserver, the same script give the following error.

> Could not connect: mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file

Here are a few things I already :

1. I tried changing the password through mysql console.
2. fulshed previlges.
3. changed the following line in config.ini.php of phpMyAdmin from

   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = '**mysqli**' 
   to

   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = '**mysql**'

With no avail.

The error message refers to a **my.cnf** file which does not exist in this version of mysql. So I assumed it must be the **my.ini**, but nothing there mentions old-passwords.

How do I get this thing to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1575807/259457

Comment: I followed everything as mentioned in  your link, I still get the error.

Comment: I have changed the password
from mysql console like this:
`SET PASSWORD FOR 'username'@'localhost' = OLD_PASSWORD('newpwd')`;

Comment: `OLD_PASSWORD`? Just use `PASSWORD` and you should be fine then, this is the same as in the duplicate question, so you just did not follow that. Just use the new password function, not the old one.