# Remote mySQL connection throws “cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication with wampserver

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

After surfing through multiple threads on here to determine why this is occuring, I'm having no luck, and wondering if WAMPservers MySQL is somehow configured oddly to where commands such as old_password=0 in the my.ini file (apparently WAMPserver doesn't use my.cnf?), and rebuilding the password using SET password=PASSWORD('your current password'); doesnt' work.

Has anyone using WAMPserver ran into such an issue, and if so, ever found a solution at all? If it helps, using the latest version of WAMPserver, mysql 5.5, PHP 5.3.10

EDIT: Have tried the [following posted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575807/cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-old-authentication) with no luck. I get the following response on screen.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2000] mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file

#0 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(251): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(340): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Type/Db/Pdo/Mysql.php(45): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(93): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Type_Db_Pdo_Mysql->getConnection(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(297): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_read')
#8 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Abstract.php(312): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->_getConnection('read')
#9 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Mysql4/Cache.php(41): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#10 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(434): Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Cache->getAllOptions()
#11 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(469): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#12 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1144): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#13 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#14 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(310): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#15 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(395): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#16 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(329): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#17 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /usr/local/www/apache24/data/webApp/app/index.php(193): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

Suggested operation has been executed that was posted in the error message, and verification that PDO support for Mysql has been confirmed.

Comment: have you checked if the mysql server allows remote connection for the user you are using. it is by default off

Comment: What version is the remote MySQL server running? Is it actually a remote server or is it part of the WAMP install?

Comment: @yakatz the MySQL server in question is part of the WAMP install. The web and MySQL servers are on the same system.

Answer (score 0):

strong textHave you got more than one MySQL server running on your system?

You say you installed MySQL 5.5.x but the error message quotes MySQL 4.1.

Check your windows services, WAMPServers MySQL is called `wampmysql` If you see another MySQL service running, uninstall it.

Also try looking for these files `my.ini` and `my.cnf`. If you have either of these files that exist OUTSIDE the Wamp folders delete them. Sometimes systems have them in the c:\windows folder structure and they get read before the correct ones in the c:\wamp... folders.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

If there is no **service called `wampmysql`** when you view the Windows Services then somehow it did not get installed.

Do this to manually install the wampmysql service.

```
left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Install Service
```

Then stop and restart all services using the wampmanager menu.

Comment: mysqld exists, but there is no wampmysql. There is no other installation of mysql outside of wampserver

Only instance of my.* is my.ini mentioned in the original question. It is located within the bin folder of wampserver

Comment: See the Additional Info I added to my answer.

Comment: Clicked on Install service and restarted. No change. Still no wampmysql showing but there is a mysql showing that does disappear from running programs if wampserver is shut down.