# error occurs while connecting PDO on server

Tags: php, mysql

this is my code it's working in local host but not in server

```
     $dbtype = 'mysql';                 // Normally mysql
     $host = 'localhost';                   // This is normally set to localhost
     $db_username = 'name';                         // DB username
     $db_password = 'pass';                     // DB password
     $db_name = 'db_name';                          // DB database name
     $dbprefix = 'db_';                 // Do not change unless you need to!
     $cat_table="db_cat";   

    try
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';port=2082;dbname='.$db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
     }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {

        die($e);
    }
    ?>
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2000] mysqlnd cannot connect to
 MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). 
This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in 
other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag
 from your my.cnf file' in /home/jeywigki/public_html/hotel/db/config.php:13 Stack trace: 
#0 /home/jeywigki/public_html/hotel/db/config.php(13): PDO-
>__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'table', 'pass') #1 /home/jeywigki/public_html/hotel/index.php(3): require_once('/home/jeywigki/...') #2 {main}
```

kindly help me.
thanks in advance

Comment: what's unclear with the error you get?

Comment: i don't know how to resolve it?

Comment: isn't it written with plain English right in place?

Comment: Even though this is local host, you shouldn't put your username and password's onto sites like this!

Comment: Googling `mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication` returns **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575807/cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-old-authentication**. Please put in some effort in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it could be the issue.

you can try this:
 `mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name`  inside in quotes.

```
  try
    {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $db_username, $db_password);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        exit('Error Connecting To DataBase');
    }
```

[docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: @Awlad Liton i tried this inside in quotes but it's not working.