# Could not connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old insecure authentication

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, password-hash, mysqlnd

**I know that there have been a lot of questions raised with the same concern as mine, but I hope you can help me find out another solution for this.**

We are using **Symfony 2.5.10**, **PHP 5.4.44** and **MySQL 4.1.20** for our project.

Whenever I attempt to log in to the system or any act that concerns connecting to the database (*e.g adding new user using FOS commands*), I receive this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2000] mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file

We already tried setting `old_passwords` in `my.cnf` to 0, restart mysql, set a new password for the mysql user and restart mysql again but still the same. And whenever we run this in the query window:

```
SELECT user, Length(Password) FROM mysql.user;
```

it still shows 16 as the length of the password of the user we are using. And also when checking the mysql server variables and settings, `old passwords` is **ON** (even though we already set old_password to 0 in my.cnf).

What could be wrong with this? I would really appreciate your help.

**Update:** For the meantime, we remove the db user's password for us to be able to access the database. But I'm still looking for other solutions since those solutions I found on the net (like removing or commenting out `old_passwords=1` in my.cnf, setting old_passwords to 0 and setting new password then restart) didn't work for me.

**Another Update:** Commonly, the solution for this problem would be setting `old_passwords` off in mysql but then, as mentioned in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php),

> the new mysqlnd library does not read mysql configuration files (my.cnf/my.ini).

So does this mean that setting `old_passwords` to in 0 in `my.cnf` has no use? I still haven't figure out solution to this problem.

Do we need an upgrade in any of the platforms used? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Possible a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575807/cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-old-authentication

Comment: Did you execute `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` ?

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575807/cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-old-authentication

Comment: have you tried.. whilst in the db admin SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password') ??

Comment: @Stafox I only have limited access, I don't have such privilege.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets I already tried resetting the password couple of times yet still the same. And whenever I check the password length, it's always 16 even though I tried running `SET SESSION old_passwords=FALSE;` before setting another password and even modifying my.cnf as I've mentioned above. :(

Comment: Can you do a `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'your_hostmask_here';` ?

Comment: Try `SET PASSWORD = UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('yourpassword'))));` THis is what the PASSWORD function does under the hood.

Comment: @Machavity After running `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'%';` here's the result: `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' `

Comment: @Mihai whenever I run `SET PASSWORD = UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('yourpassword'))));` it shows an error in the SQL syntax.

Answer (score 4):

"SET PASSWORD" is deprecated in MySQL server 5.7.6.

The syntax to be followed for servers below 5.7.6 is,

```
SET PASSWORD [FOR user] = password_option
password_option: {
    PASSWORD('auth_string')
  | OLD_PASSWORD('auth_string')
  | 'hash_string'
}
```

The syntax to be followed for servers 5.7.6 and above is,

```
SET PASSWORD [FOR user] = password_option
password_option: {
    PASSWORD('auth_string')
  | 'auth_string'
}
```

Also refer-> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html

Comment: They are using MySQL 4.1.20 not MySQL 5.7.6 so it should work ;)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this solution

http://laravel.io/forum/04-16-2014-solving-mysqlnd-cannot-connect-to-mysql-41

As per the solution you just need to set the password again and specify that it be saved in the new format.

```
mysql> SET @@session.old_passwords = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
SET PASSWORD FOR 'existinguser'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('existingpass');
Query OK, 1 rows affected (0.00 sec);
```

Comment: I tried this but it has still the same output.. `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2000] mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication...`