# Ubuntu 16.04 mysql_old_password cannot be loaded

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I want to connect to the mysql database on the external server with shell command. Ubuntu version 16.04.

```
 mysql -uXXXXXX -pYYYYYY -h domain.com
```

I get error:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'mysql_old_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/mysql_old_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I think /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/mysql_old_password.so is not exist. Please check it.

Comment: older password versions have been deprecated in recent MySQL versions. from 5.7.5 onwards, you need a hashed password, see also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-hashing.html

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you simply need to install the mysql (mariadb) client by running like:

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-client
```

The above command fixed it on my Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS installation when I had this very issue.

Comment: I gues mariadb uses old_password as for 2022 it worked for me too.

Answer (score 2):

Password hashing has changed since MySQL 5.7.5, so many clients and recent MySQL versions don't support unsafe, pre-4.1 passwords anymore.

To make your password more secure, follow the steps from [Cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575807/cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-old-authentication)

With access to the server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1576473/1875965
Check your current configuration and the current password settings, find and change users with old passwords

*Without* access to the server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901706/1875965
Connect to the server with an old client, change your password and update the settings

Answer (score -1):

what is the version of your mysql ?

The old password hashing method has been deprecated.

> Plugins that perform native authentication that matches the password against the Password column of the account row. The mysql_native_password plugin implements authentication based on the native password hashing method. The mysql_old_password plugin implements native authentication based on the older (pre-4.1) password hashing method (and is now deprecated).

you can try passing the plugin option like,

```
mysql --default-auth=mysql_old_password -u XXXXXX -pYYYYYY -h domain.com
```

Reference: [7.1.2 The Old Native Authentication Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.6/en/old-native-authentication-plugin.html)

Comment: this won't work if your version of mysql is more recent. re-configure your password using the steps on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575807/cannot-connect-to-mysql-4-1-using-old-authentication (the second answer works with a client that supports an older version of mysql if you don't have access to the msyql server)